# Is something wrong with my slugified url paths?

Tags: python, django

I am using slugify to take the name of a university and make them into slugs. I then have them in the url paths, however it is return the `page not found error`

Here are my urls.

Project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
#from ads import views
#from spider import views
#from stats import views
from listings import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
#    url(r'^ads/',include('ads.urls',namespace='ads')),
    url(r'^university/',include('listings.urls',namespace='listings')),
#    url(r'^spider/',include('spider.urls',namespace='spider')),
#    url(r'^stats/',include('stats.urls',namespace='stats')),
]
```

app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from listings import views

app_name = 'listings'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<u_slug>\w+)$',views.UniversityView.as_view(),name='university_homepage'),
    url(r'^(?P<university>\w+)/(?P<u_slug>\w+)$',views.ListingView.as_view(),name='listing_detail'),
]
```

Here's the 404:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/university/temple-university
```

Everything looks fine to but I've also been looking at this for a while so I could be overlooking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern matcher only matches a word character, and it does not match a `-`

Change

```
url(r'^(?P<u_slug>\w+)$',views.UniversityView.as_view(),name='university_homepage'),
```

to

```
url(r'^(?P<u_slug>[-\w]+)$',views.UniversityView.as_view(),name='university_homepage'),
```